# How to make JavaScript promise wait for another promise to be resolved inside for() loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, promise, angular-promise

I have an AngularJS application, which I use promises to get data from firebase database.

Here is my `home-controller`:

```
$scope.wallets;

walletDAO.getWalletsByUserId(auth.uid)
.then(function(wallets){
    $scope.wallets = wallets;
    $scope.$apply();
})
.catch(function(error){
    console.log(error);
});
```

These are my two methods inside an service I call `walletDAO`:

```
this.getWalletsByUserId = function(id) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        //codigo aqui
        var dbRef = database.ref("users/" + auth.currentUser.uid);
        dbRef.on('value', function(data) {
            //console.log("Wallet IDs Retrieved!");
            var userOnDB = data.val();
            var walletIds = userOnDB.wallets;
            var wallets = [];
            for (i = 0; i < walletIds.length; i++) {
                var x = getWalletById(walletIds[i])
                .then(function(wallet){
                    wallets.push(wallet);
                })
                .catch(function(error){
                    console.log(error);
                });
            }
            resolve(wallets);
        }, function(error) {
            reject(error);
        });
    });
};

var getWalletById = function(id) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var dbRef = database.ref("wallets/" + id);
        dbRef.on('value', function(data) {
            //console.log("Wallet Retrieved!");
            var wallet = data.val();
            //console.log(wallet);
            resolve(wallet);
        }, function(error) {
            reject(error);
        });
    });
};
```

The second method, `getWalletById`, receive an wallet `ID` and return an `wallet` object from the firebase database. this mehod is called on the first method, `getWalletsByUserId` inside a `for` loop, which should wait for the second method to return the wallet before iterate to the next, so it can push it into the array. The problem is that it dont wait and the code execute the `.then()` method on the `home-controller` before the resolving of the `getWalletById`, leaving the `$scope.wallets` empty.

Any advice?

Comment: `Promise.all()` is your friend for getting notified when a whole `for` loop of promises is actually done.  There are dozens of answers here that show you how to do that if you can't figure it out after reading about `Promise.all()`.

Comment: Use [$q.when](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#when) to convert ES6 promises to promises that are integrated with AngularJS and its digest cycle. See [AngularJS display a promise from Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43734062/angualrjs-display-a-promise-from-firebase/43742980#43742980).

Comment: The latest version of the Firebase API already returns ES6 promises. There is no need to manufacture one with `new  Promise(function(resolve,reject){})`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`$q.all()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all) to wait for all sub-promises to complete

```
$q.all(walletIds.map(function(id){
  return getWalletById(id);
})).then(function(wallets){
  ...
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of manufacturing an ES6 promise from the [ref.on](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#on) method, use the [ref.once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once) method and bring it into the AngularJS execution context with [$q.when](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#when):

```
function getWalletById(id) {
    var dbRef = database.ref("wallets/" + id);
    var es6Promise = dbRef.once('value');
    return $q.when(es6Promise);
}
```

Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

---

Use [$q.all](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all) and [promise chaining](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises) in the parent function:

```
this.getWalletsByUserId = function(id) {
    var dbRef = database.ref("users/" + auth.currentUser.uid);
    var es6Promise = dbRef.once('value')
      .then(function(snapshot)
        //console.log("Wallet IDs Retrieved!");
        var userOnDB = snapshot.val();
        var walletIds = userOnDB.wallets;
        var promiseList = walletIds.map(function(id){
            return getWalletById(id);
        });
        return $q.all(promiseList);
    });
    return $q.when(es6Promise);
};
```

The `.then` method *returns a new promise* which is resolved or rejected via the return value of the `successCallback`, `errorCallback` (unless that value is a promise, in which case it is resolved with the value which is resolved in that promise using [promise chaining](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/#toc-promises-queues)).